# How do I set a login password in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, login, password

I thought this would be a common question but after searching for answers I couldn't find anything that addresses this exact problem.

Anyway, I have an administrative password, so every time I want to install an update or gain root privilege, I am asked to enter it. However, I want to set this password for logging in so other people can't access my account (which is the only account on my laptop). I went to:
'System Tools' > 'Users & Groups'
and in the [Users Settings] window it is supposedly set like this 'Password: asked on login'
But this is not the case because it never requests my password when I log in. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You should go to: 'System Tools' > 'Users & Groups' and check or uncheck **Don't ask for password on login**

[image]

Comment: I done that already but it didn't work. There might just be a bug. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From terminal:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

delete

```
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=0
```